# Как заставить opencv на python проигрывать видео, которое уже проигрывается в веб камеры?

Tags: python, opencv

По сути нужно создать loop внутри loop-а, чтобы проигрывалось лайв-видео за источник которого берется другое лайв-видео. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы видео сохранялось на носитель и сразу же проигрывалось с него? Если да, то как? Код с попыткой сделать что-то подобное ниже. ORB detector на процесс влиять не должен.

```
import cv2
width = 640 
height = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') 
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
    while True:

     frame_read = cap
     ret, myFrame = cap.read()
     img = cv2.resize(myFrame, (width, height))
     orb = cv2.ORB_create()
     kp = orb.detect(img, None)
     kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
     img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, img, color=(255, 0, 255))
     img2 = cv2.flip(img2, 0)
     out.write(img2)

     cv2.imshow('test', img2)


        while True:
           test = cap.open('output.avi')

           frame_read = test
           ret, kpFrame = test.read()
           img3 = cv2.resize(kpFrame, (width, height))
           cv2.imshow('test2', img3)
          
           if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
```